# How to use div from another file.js? [SPA]

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application, cart

I'm trying to make a cart on page, and to show how many items it chosen right now. I'm trying to choosing rooms, and everything working fine, but when I'm trying to show it on page with cart, it shows me Error, that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at cartNumbers (rooms.js:66)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (rooms.js:56)"

I imported file, trying to use $(#card).load(//code), but it's not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
import { cart } from "./cart";

export const rooms = () => {
  const fragment = $(new DocumentFragment());

  $.getJSON(
    "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/ulatowskap/demo/rooms",
    function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var name = value.name;
        var beds = value.beds;
        var guests = value.guests;
        var price = value.price;

        $(".output").append(`
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100 border-0 shadow">
          <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placebear.com/750/200" alt=""></a>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h4 class="card-title mb-0">
              <a href="#" class="name mb-0 text-dark">${name}</a>
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text guests text-black-50">Ilość osób: ${guests}</p>
            <p class="card-text price text-black-50">Cena: ${price} zł</p>
            <p class="card-text beds text-black-50"> Ilość łóżek: ${beds}</p>
          </div>
          <button class="add-cart" href="#">Add to cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      `);
      });

      let carts = document.querySelectorAll(".add-cart");
      let name = name;
      let beds = beds;
      let guests = guests;
      let price = price;

      let products = [
        {
          name: name,
          beds: beds,
          guests: guests,
          price: price,
        },
      ];

      for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
        carts[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
          cartNumbers();
        });
      }

      function cartNumbers() {
        let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");
        productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

        if (productNumbers) {
          localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + 1);
          document.querySelector(".cart").textContent = productNumbers + 1;
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", 1);
        }
      }
    }
  );

  const roomsPage = $(
    `<div class="output container">  <h1 class="my-4">Pokoje do wynajęcia </h1></div>`
  );

  fragment.append(roomsPage);
  return fragment;
};
```

And I'm trying to show it here, in div with "cart" class:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import { rooms } from "./rooms";

export const cart = () => {
  const fragment = $(new DocumentFragment());
  const cartPage = $(`<div class="cart">
0
    </div>`);

  fragment.append(cartPage);

  return fragment;
};
```

Please, help.

Comment: I don't see you ever calling `cart()`

Comment: I put it in my code, but it still doesn't work properly. Where should I add it correctly?